# ArgumentException caught while trying to enter connection string

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, connection-string

I am trying to develop a very simple Student Enrollment System, and as I built and compiled my solution, an ArgumentException was caught near my connection string. The exception message displayed is this:

```
Keyword not supported: '@datasource'.
```

I checked for inner exceptions and the exception details, but found nothing that can give me the slightest of hint about the reason behind this exception.

What am I doing wrong??? Is it syntactical error??? Or did I get my connection string wrong???? Can anyone point it out please????

Here's my code where the exception is getting caught:

```
    #region Database Connection
    public SimpleEnrollmentSystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //creating a connection
        connection = new SqlConnection();
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        connection.ConnectionString = "@DataSource = SAADMAAN;" +
            "Initial Catalog=db_student;User ID=sa;Password=***********";

        updateReady = false;
        insertReady = false;   
    }
    #endregion
```

I also have a database named db_student in SQL Server 2012. The only table I have there is named Students, which is structured in the following way:

```
  CREATE TABLE Students
  (
  StudentID int unique primary key,
  FirstName varchar(50),
  LastName varchar(50),
  Gender varchar(10),
  Age int,
  Address varchar(MAX)
  )
```

Note that I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/. I assume you are trying to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Please check my update to the post.

Comment: In that case I believe apomenes' answer is correct. The website is a great resource for valid connection strings to a wide range of data sources. You can use it to help you figure out these types of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = SAADMAAN;" +
            "Initial Catalog=db_student;User ID=sa;Password=***********";
```

**EDIT :**

Be sure to leave a space beetween `Data` and `Source` and `@` out of string literal

Comment: Nope. still getting the same exception.

Comment: Thanks. Leaving a space between 'data' and 'source' solved the problem. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using:

```
 connection = new SqlConnection("data source=SAADMAAN;initial catalog=db_student;User ID=sa;Password=***********");
```